# How to assign the list of elements to empty list of pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Its old code and working file in pandas old version 1x but not working in pandas latest version --  2.0.3.
temp_df['data'],values.tolist() is having list of elements but list assignment is not happening .
Data frame returning empty list .

```
data = {"ID":{"0":"2","1":"20","2":"201","3":"2011","4":"206","5":"2061","6":"2062","7":"2063"},"Name":{"0":"Page","1":"Detailspage","2":"User Page","3":"User detailed page","4":"Result","5":"Res","6":"Res","7":"Res3"},"PATH":{"0":"/","1":"/Detailspage","2":"/UserPage","3":"/User detailed page","4":"Result","5":"Result / Res1","6":"Result / Res2","7":"Result / Res3"},"TYPE":{"0":"Page","1":"Page","2":"P/T","3":"Tile","4":"P/T","5":"T","6":"T","7":"T","8":"T"}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['details'] = [[] for _ in range(df.shape[0])]

df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)

for i in range(0, len(df)):
        i_id = df.iloc[i]['ID']

    
        temp_df = (df.loc[df.ID.str.contains(f'^{i_id}\d$'), :])
       

        if len(temp_df) > 0:
               
                print("@@",temp_df['PATH'].values.tolist())
                df.at[i,'details'] = temp_df['PATH'].values.tolist()
# df = df
print(df["details"])

Expected Output:
['/UserPage', 'Result']
['/User detailed page']
['Result / Res1', 'Result / Res2', 'Result / Res3']

But getting Error :
```

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Can any one help me how to assign List to list of data frame .

Answer (score 0):

Use `.at` for this type of assignement (unlike `loc` or `iloc` it cannot return a slice so pandas knows that you are trying to set the value of a single entry to a list), see:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'i':range(3)})
df['details'] = [[] for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
i=2
df.at[i, "details"] = list('abc')
df

#   i   details
# 0     0   []
# 1     1   []
# 2     2   [a, b, c]
```

Edit:
I seem to be able to make your example work when replacing this line `temp_df = (df.loc[df.ID.str.contains(f'^{i_id}\d$'), :])` with `temp_df = df[df.ID.str.contains(f'^{i_id}\d$').fillna(False)]`. The problem comes from the `NaN` values in your ID columns fyi.

Edit2:
Seeing your comment and that you are using pandas 2.0.x I tried my solution on the same pandas version and got the error you mentioned, same as you. Here is a workaround:

```py
data = {"ID":{"0":"2","1":"20","2":"201","3":"2011","4":"206","5":"2061","6":"2062","7":"2063"},"Name":{"0":"Page","1":"Detailspage","2":"User Page","3":"User detailed page","4":"Result","5":"Res","6":"Res","7":"Res3"},"PATH":{"0":"/","1":"/Detailspage","2":"/UserPage","3":"/User detailed page","4":"Result","5":"Result / Res1","6":"Result / Res2","7":"Result / Res3"},"TYPE":{"0":"Page","1":"Page","2":"P/T","3":"Tile","4":"P/T","5":"T","6":"T","7":"T","8":"T"}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['details'] = [[] for _ in range(df.shape[0])]

df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)

for i in range(0, len(df)):
        i_id = df.iloc[i]['ID']

    
        temp_df = df[df.ID.str.contains(f'^{i_id}\d$').fillna(False)]
       

        if len(temp_df) > 0:
               
                print("@@",temp_df['PATH'].values.tolist())
                df.iat[i,-1].extend(temp_df['PATH'].values.tolist()) #-1 for last column ("details"), using extend to modify the empty list in place (your logic only updates it once)
# df = df
print(df["details"])
```

It seems like `at` and `iat` have been updated to not accept an iterable on the right hand side. So I resolved to using `list.extend` to update the empty list entries with values, since your logic only updates them once. It should work here, but not a very generalizable solution I reckon.

Comment: After trying this approach getting below error:

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: Can you update your post to share what you are doing now?

Comment: Each time i'm assigning different size of list to dataframe

Comment: I don't why this would be an issue. Does my example work on your environment? Can you share an example for me to reproduce your error?

Comment: I have edited my question to reproduce the error

Comment: @Madhavi check my update I have something working on your example

Comment: I feel issue is not with NAN values  after using ur modified code got same issue :  ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: Indeed, I managed to reproduce your error by udpating my pandas 1.5.x to 2.0.2. See my edit for an updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.at[i, 'details'] = temp_df['data'].values.tolist()
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).